# Regex phone number with stars

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string, function

the following function transforms a phone number such as +33286487648 into +332******48.

```
formatPhoneWithStar = function(phone) {

    const prefixLength = 4;
    const suffixLength = 3;

    const prefix  = phone.substring(0, prefixLength);
    const suffix  = phone.slice(-suffixLength);
    const nbStars = phone.length - (prefixLength + suffixLength);

    let formattedPhone = prefix;
    for (let i = 0; i < nbStars; i++) {
       formattedPhone += '*';
    }
    formattedPhone += suffix;

    return formattedPhone;
}
```

However, I would like to avoid the use of a forloop (nodeJS purpose). I am wondering if the same function could be done using regular expressions ?

I already tried a few ones like

```
([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{3})\w+
```

and  then I would like to use $1 and $3 such as  $1 + [how  to generate star] + $3. Does anyone know if  this is doable without using a for loop and using regex ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/vO9mS6/1)?

Comment: Yeah it's what i have so  far on regex  website. Now, how can I use that in my function?

Answer (score 3):

No need to use regex here, just use `"*".repeat(nbStars)`:

```js
phone ="+33286487648";
prefixLength = 4;
suffixLength = 3;

prefix  = phone.substring(0, prefixLength);
suffix  = phone.slice(-suffixLength);
nbStars = phone.length - (prefixLength + suffixLength);

formattedPhone = prefix + "*".repeat(nbStars) + suffix;

console.log(formattedPhone);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
'+33286487648'.replace(/^(\+?\d{3})(\d+)(\d{2})$/, function() {
  return arguments[1] + arguments[2].replace(/./g, '*') + arguments[3];
}); // Produces '+332******48'
```

---

Or perhaps a little easier on the eyes (inspired by `.repeat` from other answers):

```js
function hideMiddle(string, prefixLength, suffixLength) {
  var re = new RegExp('^(\\+?\\d{' + prefixLength + '})(\\d+)(\\d{' + suffixLength + '})$');

  return string.replace(re, function(match, prefix, middle, suffix) {
    return prefix + '*'.repeat(middle.length) + suffix;
  });
}
console.log(hideMiddle('+33286487648', 3, 2));
console.log(hideMiddle('+33286487648', 1, 1));
```

Comment: I really like your solution!! However, i need to replace the {3} by a variable. I read that it needs to  be escaped with \\, am ii right ?

Comment: @XimaBrabTobra Revised to support parameterized lengths. However, I must say that the non-regex solution of Thomas Ayoub is more readable. In short, I see no real benefit of regex over string manipulation here.

Answer (score 0):

With regex + replacement:

```js
    var phone = "+33286487648";
    var m = phone.match(/(\+\d{3})(\d+)(\d{3})/);
    var res = m[1] + '*'.repeat(m[2].length) + m[3];
    console.log(res);
```